# How can i load only specific tab contents (JS file) when i enter on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a page that shows a lot of Magic: The Gathering cards and they content are showed with tabs. I have tabs for every type of card. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript but with help here i created and adapted a JS file that loads all MTG cards (PNG files of Magic: The Gathering game) from directories according to their types, above i show an example of land cards:

```
`const land_cards = [
"lands/dragonskull-summit",
"lands/drowned-catacomb",
"lands/field-of-ruin",
"lands/glacial-fortress",
"lands/rootbound-crag",
"lands/unclaimed-territory",
"lands/unknow-shores"
];
for (let card of land_cards) {
    $('#land-cards').append('<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">')
}`
```

This script works well, but there's just one problem: when i enter on this page (card-database.html), all cards are loaded at same time, and it's a huge quantity of cards that i have here. My question is: can i edit to it load only the selected tab content when i enter on this page? Example:

- Actual situation: i enter on card-database.html and all 500 cards are loaded at the same time, "black cards" tab is selected by default.
- Wanted situation: i enter on card-database.html and only the selected tab cards are loaded (black cards), and if i click on another tab (land cards, for example), it will load all land cards.

Here's  the code of the page, if needed:

```
<!-- TAB MENU -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#black-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Black</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blue-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#green-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
            <li><a href="#red-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
            <li><a href="#white-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#multicolored-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Multicolored</a></li>
            <li><a href="#artifacts-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Artifacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#land-cards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lands</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- TAB BLACK CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="black-cards">                  
            </div>
            <!-- TAB BLUE CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="blue-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB GREEN CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="green-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB RED CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="red-cards">  
            </div>
            <!-- TAB WHITE CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="white-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB MULTICOLORED CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="multicolored-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB ARTIFACTS CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="artifacts-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB LANDS CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="land-cards">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
```

Can you guys help me to do that? Any suggestion or material that i can use to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: PS: someone told me to do this with Ajax from webserver. How can i do that? If i have a account on shared server, can i make this happen with Ajax? Or i can only modify/do this on dedicated/vps servers? Sorry about those noob questions :P

Comment: [Lazy loading](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/). Options #3 and #4 are easy to implement without significant programming effort. You might also want to go through [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/).

Comment: How do you currently load the card information?

Comment: Thank you @AndreiGheorghiu, i'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Add your images for all types and complete the list.

```js
const cards ={
lands:[
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_jokerblack-128.png",
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_jokerblack-128.png",
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_jokerblack-128.png",
],
black:[
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_acespad-256.png",
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_acespad-256.png",
"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards/512/card_acespad-256.png",
],
blue:[
"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards-1/154/poker-card-two-red-256.png",
"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards-1/154/poker-card-two-red-256.png",
"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/poker-cards-1/154/poker-card-two-red-256.png",
],
//....
};

$('.card-type').on('click',function(ev){
  $('.tab-pane').empty();
  let type = $(ev.target).data('type');
  for (let card of cards[type]) {
  $('#'+type+'-cards').append('<img src="'+card+'">')
    //$('#'+type+'-cards').append('<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">')
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- TAB MENU -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#black-cards" data-type='black' class="card-type" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Black</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blue-cards" class="card-type" data-type='blue' role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
          <!-- add the others-->
            <li><a href="#land-cards" class="card-type"   role="tab" data-type='lands' data-toggle="tab">Lands</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- TAB BLACK CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="black-cards">                  
            </div>
            <!-- TAB BLUE CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="blue-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB GREEN CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="green-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB RED CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="red-cards">  
            </div>
            <!-- TAB WHITE CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="white-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB MULTICOLORED CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="multicolored-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB ARTIFACTS CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="artifacts-cards">
            </div>
            <!-- TAB LANDS CARDS CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="lands-cards">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Hello @Cristian Tr! I tried your solution, but not worked :( 

Strange, when i copy the exactly code (that works on snippet here to show this URL src) don't show anything on my page. I edited all parts of the code to make sure that nothing is wrong or missing, but don't worked. Maybe it's some problem with my CSS, height of tabs, don't know. I'll try to make some changes on my CSS to see if it works. Thanks for the try!